# leafletjs.elevation won't show gpx

Tags: leaflet, gpx, elevation

I updated leaflet elevation example gpx just changing the gox name, working locally on win 7 or OS X and Safari or Chrome. Nothing shows up.

```js
  var map = new L.Map('map');

  var url = 'http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg',
   attr ='Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/">MapQuest</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
   service = new L.TileLayer(url, {subdomains:"1234",attribution: attr});

  var el = L.control.elevation();
  el.addTo(map);
  var g=new L.GPX("./maggiore.gpx", {
   async: true,
    marker_options: {
       startIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-start.png',
       endIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-end.png',
       shadowUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-shadow.png'
     }
  });
  g.on('loaded', function(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  });
  g.on("addline",function(e){
   el.addData(e.line);
  });
  g.addTo(map);
  map.addLayer(service);
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
 <title>Leaflet.Elevation</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       padding:0px;
       margin:0px;
    } 
 </style>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.ie.css" /><![endif]-->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/Leaflet.Elevation-0.0.2.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/Leaflet.Elevation-0.0.2.min.js"></script
 ><script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/leaflet-gpx/gpx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="map"></div>
```

All I get is a grey page with zoom control and an empty diagram

Answer (score 0):

do you have the leaftlet.elevation dist files ?
looking at your example you have :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/Leaflet.Elevation-0.0.2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/Leaflet.Elevation-0.0.2.min.js"></script
```

you may copy these files to the lib folder.

Comment: Yes, I got all the files in place